# How do i build a project with mono via cmd line?

Tags: mono, compilation

I must use the commandline/terminal and i need to use gmcs and not xbuild.

How do i compile a project? My one liner looks like this

```
gmcs -d:mydef -lib:my_ref_folder -debug -r:System.Web,System.Data,mysql.data -recurse:'*.cs'
```

The problem is i get the error `error CS0006: cannot find metadata file`mysql.data'`. I googled and i tried`gacutil -i name.dll` as many suggested but after installing mysql i still got that error. I also neeed lucence.net and when i use gacutil with it i get the error

```
# sudo gacutil -i Lucene.Net.dll
Failure adding assembly Lucene.Net.dll to the cache: Attempt to install an assembly without a strong name
```

How do i build a project with gmcs? i tried googling examples but gmcs isnt a great keyword and i am stumpped with the man pages. -lib: doesnt work and neither does -L my_ref_folder Both dlls/references in the older are not found and i get the `cannot find metadata file` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a one liner

> gmcs "/out:myfile.dll" -t:library
>   -r:System,System.Data "/r:/home/user/path/Lucene.Net.dll"
>   "/r:/home/user/path/mysql.data.dll"
>   /nologo /warn:4 /debug:+ /debug:full
>   /optimize- /codepage:utf8
>   "/define:TRACE;DEBUG"
>   -recurse:'/home/user/path/*.cs'